# Do the odoo create and write method when the save button is click

Tags: odoo

this my class in odoo

```
class medical_procedure_base(models.Model):
   _name = 'health_administrator.medical_procedure_base'
   _description = 'Medical Procedure'

   name = fields.Char(string='Libellé', required=True)
   code = fields.Char(string='Code', required=True)
   key_letter = fields.Many2one('health_administrator.key_letter', required=True, string="Lettre clé")
   medical_procedure_cat_id = fields.Many2one('health_administrator.medical_procedure_category', required=True, string="Catégorie de l'acte")
   amount = fields.Integer(string="Valeur lettre clé", required=True, default=0)

_order = 'code asc'
```

What I want, is when i clicked on Save Button from Odoo make a search this model to get all 'Medical Procedure' that have the same key_letter id and medical_procedure_cat_id id in that model and do the odoo create or write method.

Thanks

Comment: and what you want to do with the result?!!!

Comment: Hi @Cherif, with the result i want to use the create method of odoo to insert it in the table also use the write method to update it. Thank

Answer (score 0):

Call `super` for both `create` and `write` function.

> Create

```
@api.model
def create(self,vals):
    #your code
    return super(your_class_name,self).create(vals)
```

> Write

```
@api.model
def write(self,vals):
    #your code
    return super(your_class_name,self).write(vals)
```

NB:`Create` is called when the record is created and `write` is called when the record is edited.